# delphi как сделать градиент прозрачности формы?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать градиент прозрачности формы?
Как сделать уровень прозрачности это одно градиент прозрачности эт другое.
Покажите любой способ или место где вы это видели в коде или какие WinApi методы для этого есть.

На картинке показан пример эффекта но нужно именно для окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну вот теперь все работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: layered windows были. вы бы вместе с окном показали как должно выглядеть. А то на картинке все и так знаю как выглядит градиент. и версию ОС

Comment: @teran у меня примера нет. представьте что облака это рабочий стол а белая форма это моя программа. Win 10

Comment: Предполагаг, что создать градиент в PNG, и натянуть прозрачность PNG на окно https://habr.com/ru/post/146101/

Comment: @Герман Борисов пойдет спс.